# .htaccess and magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I am trying to use `.htaccess` to handle the 404s but for some reason the default page CMS/indes/noRoute keeps interfering, is there a way to change magento's 404 using .htaccess instead of that default no-route, the idea is to send the 404s a search result containing the keywords they were looking for. I got it to work on other sites before but on magento they have a strange way of handling 404s and I don't know how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this is by rewriting the Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Default class, which is doing the redirect to noroute. You could redirect to your own controller, which is showing the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure you can do it with .htaccess.
Please try the following code in your .htaccess file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://demowebsite.com/custom404error.php
```

The custom404error.php can be whatever webpage you want to display as your 404 error. This trick worked for me.